# keyerror inside django model class __init__

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here's a Django model class I wrote. This class gets a keyerror when I call `get_object_or_404` from Django (I conceive that keyerror is raised due to no kwargs being passed to `__init__` by the get function, arguments are all positional). Interestingly, it does not get an error when I call `get_object_or_404` from console.

I wonder why, and if the below code is the correct way (ie, using **init** to populate the link field) to construct this class.

```
class Link(models.Model)

    event_type = models.IntegerField(choices=EVENT_TYPES)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    isActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def _generate_link(self):
        prelink = str(self.user.id)+str(self.event_type)+str(self.created_on)
        m = md5.new()
        m.update(prelink)
        return m.hexdigest()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs['user'].pop()
        self.event_type = kwargs['event_type'].pop()
        self.link = self._generate_link()
        super(Link,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: Considering the answers, it seems that overriding init is problematic. I will restructure the class following your suggestions. Thanks, everybody. (BTW, I still don't get why whether an exception is thrown or not depends on where it is called from - console or Django).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to write your own `__init__` for Django model classes.  I think you'll be a lot happier without it.

Almost anything you think you want to do in `__init__` can be better done in `save`.

Answer (score 7):

```
self.user = kwargs['user'].pop()
self.event_type = kwargs['event_type'].pop()
```

You're trying to retrieve an entry from the dictionary, and then call its pop method. If you want to remove and return an object from a dictionary, call `dict.pop()`:

```
self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
```

Of course, this will fail with a `KeyError` when `"user"` is not present in `kwargs`. You'll want to provide a default value to pop:

```
self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
```

This means "if `"user"` is in the dictionary, remove and return it. Otherwise, return `None`".

Regarding the other two lines:

```
self.link = self._generate_link()
super(Link,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

`super().__init__()` will set `link` to something, probably `None`. I would reverse the lines, to something like this:

```
super(Link,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
self.link = self._generate_link()
```

You might want to add a test before setting the link, to see if it already exists (`if self.link is not None: ...`). That way, links you pass into the constructor won't be overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need the `__init__` here at all.

You are always calculating the value of link when the class is instantiated. This means you ignore whatever is stored in the database. Since this is the case, why bother with a model field at all? You would be better making link a property, with the getter using the code from `_generate_link`.

```
@property
def link(self): 
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

> wonder why, and if the below code is the correct way (ie, using `__init__` to populate the link field) to construct this class.

I once got some problems when I tried to overload `__init__`
In the maillist i got this answer

> It's best not to overload it with your own
>   `__init__`. A better option is to hook into the `post_init` signal with a
>   custom method and in that method do your `process()` and
>   `make_thumbnail()` calls.

In your case the post_init-signal should do the trick and implementing `__init__` shouldn't be necessary at all.
You could write something like this:

```
class Link(models.Model)
    event_type = models.IntegerField(choices=EVENT_TYPES)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    isActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def create_link(self):
        prelink = str(self.user.id)+str(self.event_type)+str(self.created_on)
        m = md5.new()
        m.update(prelink)
        return m.hexdigest()

def post_link_init(sender, **kwargs):
    kwargs['instance'].create_link()
post_init.connect(post_link_init, sender=Link)

>>> link = Link(event_type=1, user=aUser, created_on=datetime.now(), link='foo', isActive=True)
```

providing keyword `unique` for `link = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)` could be helpful, too. If it is not provided, get_object_or_404 may won't work in case the same value in the link-field exists several times.

[signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) and [unique](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique) in the django-docs